# How to convert an abundance matrix into a presence-absence matrix while keeping the abundance of each sample

Tags: r

I am trying to transform an abundance matrix like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMeL4.jpg)

Into a matrix like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL0EL.jpg)

This way I could keep the abundance of haplotypes in each population sampled.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
dat=data.frame(population=LETTERS[1:2],halotype1=c(2,0),halotype2=c(0,2))
m=suppressWarnings(setDT(dat)[,lapply(.SD,rep,x = 1),by=population])
replace(m,is.na(m),0)
   population halotype1 halotype2
1:          A         1         0
2:          A         1         0
3:          B         0         1
4:          B         0         1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code.

However, it seems there is a problem with the code when the matrix looks like this:

```html
Population haplotype1 haplotype2
 1     2      0
 2     1      4
```

After running the code, I would expect to have a matrix like this:

```html
Population haplotype1 haplotype2
 1     1      0
 1     1      0
 2     1      0
 2     0      1
 2     0      1
 2     0      1
 2     0      1
```

Instead, what I get is this:

```html
Population haplotype1 haplotype2
 1  1 0
 1  1 0
 2  1 1
 2  1 1
 2  1 1
 2  1 1
```

What is the code to get the matrix I am expecting?